# WSO2-Private PaaS -Claim Management

Tags: wso2, paas

I have installed and run wso2 private paas.I want to add new claim dialects but I am not able to find the option of adding claim management in Private PaaS console.
Any pointers for configuring claims for Private PaaS will be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use WSO2 Identity Server (IS) for this. WSO2 Private PaaS does not include all IS features for identity management. Configure SSO for WSO2 Private PaaS using WSO2 IS, and do claim management in WSO2 IS.

Please note that WSO2 has discontinued WSO2 Private PaaS solution and the new PaaS strategy is explained at the below link:

http://wso2.com/cloud/paas/